# pd.to_datetime with different date formats

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to analyse a large dataset with dates formatted in several different formats:

```
Mon, 04 Nov 2019 06:12:44 -0800 (PST)
Mon,  4 Nov 2019 15:16:58 +0100 (CET)
Mon,  4 Nov 2019 08:03:13 +0000 (UTC)
Mon,  4 Nov 2019 12:05:54 +0100
```

`dfMail.Date = pd.to_datetime(dfMail.Date, format = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")`

returns error: ValueError: unconverted data remains:  (PST)

What is the best strategy to convert these dates?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try just `pd.to_datetime(dfMail.Date)`?

Comment: Yes, in my 1st attempt. Result: `ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'Thu, 17 Oct 2019 23:19:41 +0100 (GMT+01:00)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the `()` extension might be troublesome. In which case, you can just ignore it:

```
pd.to_datetime(dfMail.Date.str.replace('( \(.*\))', ''), utc=True)
```

Input:

```
                                          Date
0        Mon, 04 Nov 2019 06:12:44 -0800 (PST)
1        Mon,  4 Nov 2019 15:16:58 +0100 (CET)
2        Mon,  4 Nov 2019 08:03:13 +0000 (UTC)
3              Mon,  4 Nov 2019 12:05:54 +0100
4  Thu, 17 Oct 2019 23:19:41 +0100 (GMT+01:00)
```

Output:

```
0   2019-11-04 14:12:44+00:00
1   2019-11-04 14:16:58+00:00
2   2019-11-04 08:03:13+00:00
3   2019-11-04 11:05:54+00:00
4   2019-10-17 22:19:41+00:00
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Comment: Thank you, column is indeed convereted to datetime64. However, a warning is issued: `/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py:1206: UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname UT identified but not understood.  Pass ``tzinfos`` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime.  In a future version, this will raise an exception.
  category=UnknownTimezoneWarning)`